# I define an Complex class. How can I do like this "9+Complex"

Tags: python, operator-overloading

It's my Complex class, and i overload "+"

```
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.__imag = float(imag)
        self.__real = float(real)
        self.__attr = {
            'imag': self.__imag,
            'real': self.__real
        }

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Complex):
            self.__imag += float(other.imag)
            self.__real += float(other.real)
        elif isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            self.__real += other
        else:
            print 'expect int or Complex, not {}'.format(type(other))
            raise TypeError
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return self.__attr[item]
        except TypeError as e:
            print e
            print 'no attribute{}'.format(item)
```

now, it's full if I do plus "Complex+int", but while I do plus like "int+Complex", I get this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Complex'
```

Comment: O，the indent is error, __add__,__getattr__ are both within the class!

Comment: You should probably look into `__radd__`

Comment: http://www.marinamele.com/2014/04/modifying-add-method-of-python-class.html

Comment: That should help you

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your class :

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return Complex.__add__(self,other)
```

Refer to this [LINK](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php) to learn more like `__iadd__()`.